# Is there a way to keep objects in place while scrolling on a canvas? (Tkinter)

Tags: tkinter, scrollbar

I want to make drag and drop objects that keep their position when the scrollbar is active.
So far it works well enough while within the original range of visible canvas--any pointers towards improving it would also be greatly appreciated!

My test marker lands in far less predictable spots on the canvas when I test its response outside of the original range of visible canvas.

I'm figuring the solution has something to do with the 'markerset' function bound to the 'marker' widget...

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*

sx = 90
sy = 50

def on_configure(event):
    # update scrollregion after starting 'mainloop'
    # when all widgets are in canvas
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))


def drag_start(event):
    widget = event.widget
    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y

def drag_motion(event):
    widget = event.widget
    sx = widget.winfo_x() - widget.startX + event.x
    sy = widget.winfo_y() - widget.startY + event.y

    canvas.create_window(sx, sy, window=marker)
    print(sx, sy)

def markerset(event):
    widget = event.widget

    widget.startX = event.x
    widget.startY = event.y

    sx = widget.winfo_x() + event.x    
    sy = widget.winfo_y() + event.y   

    canvas.create_window(sx, sy, window=marker)




root = tk.Tk()

# --- canvas with scrollbar ---
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill='y')

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)

# --- put frame in canvas ---
frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0,0), width=700, window=frame, anchor='nw')

# --- canvas image ---
img = PhotoImage(file="[PNG]")  #If you are testing this on your own, any larger-sized PNG 
will suffice.
canvas.create_image(20,20, anchor=NW, image=img)

# --- marker widget ---
marker = tk.Label(canvas, height=2, width=3, bg='green')
mCanvas = canvas.create_window(sx, sy, window=marker)


marker.bind("<Button-1>", drag_start)
marker.bind("<B1-Motion>", drag_motion)
marker.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", markerset)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You could try using the scrollbar `.get` method to get the current position of the scrollbar and add that to the final value of where to place the widget

Comment: I think I understand. Any leads on how I should go about trying that?

Comment: it is late and I can't think too well at the moment, but I can tell that probably when calling any of the moving functions just create a local variable that gets the current position of scrollbar, then convert that value to coordinates (because that value is probably kinda like percentage so take the whole height/width and divide by that value or sth, just take a look at the docs) and then add to the final coordinates that value or sth, in general I think it shouldn't be too hard/should be pretty simple logic

Comment: Sounds like that could work! I'll give it a try. Thanks!